# Boost C++ File System program not able to run

Tags: c++, boost

```
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;


int main()
 {
  boost::filesystem::path src("/usr/BoostCode/1.txt");
  boost::filesystem::path dst("/usr");
  boost::filesystem::copy_file(src, dst);
}
```

**What i want to do is:** copy the file "1.txt" from "/usr/BoostCode" directory to "/usr"
**Compiling:**  g++ bfs.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -o bfs
**To Run:** ./bfs

**Getting an error:** terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl > > >'
  what():  boost::filesystem::copy_file: File exists: "/usr/BoostCode/1.txt", "/usr"
Aborted

Please help whats wrong with this snippet?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: May be a permissions problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you have to specify the full destination?

```
boost::filesystem::path dst("/usr/1.txt");
```

Answer (score 3):

The `dst` variable should hold the new name of the file, not just the directory. Now you are trying to copy the file as a replacement to the directory, which fails.  See [the boost::filesystem::copy_file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#copy_file) documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Insert the line:

```
dst = dst/src.filename();
```

Put it after you create `dst`. And your program will work as you expect it to. It was complaining that `/usr` already existed and so it couldn't copy on top of it.

Comment: They've redefined operator `/` to concatenate paths in boost 8D That's great!